# How To Send Data from template in my request Django

Tags: python, django, database

I want to Send My Section Name From Drop Menu in Template (ex:Heart) to my views.py as object from Section Model

```
def SectDetails(request):

if request.method=='GET':
    sec_name=request.GET['section_name']
    context={
        'section':Section.objects.get(section_name=sec_name)
    }

    return render(request,'hospital_system/sectiondetails.html',context)
else:
    return render(request,'hospital_system/home.html')
```

then my template

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            {% for sec in sections %}
              <a method='GET' class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'Hosp-SectDetails' %}">{{sec.section_name}}</a>
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters with the `url` built-in tag, something like this should work in your case,

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
    {% for sec in sections %}
        <a method='GET' class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'Hosp-SectDetails' sec.section_name %}">{{sec.section_name}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

[Django Built-in tags and filters - Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url)